# Create a list starting with a static letter decimal number

Tags: html, css, list

I use Dreamweaver CC.  I want to create a list as follows:

```
Q1. nnn
Q2. aaa
Q3. bbb

A1. ddd
A2. dde
A3. ccc
```

I use this css:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
ol li:before {
    content: 'Q' counter(item, decimal) '. ';
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
ol li:before {
  content: 'Q' counter(item, decimal) '. ';
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ol>
```

I get:

```
1Q1.
2Q2.
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're creating, and using, css generated content to implement your own counter, using the `::before` pseudo-element, and css counters, you need to remove the native counter; otherwise your own counter (as you've seen) is appended to (or simply follows) that native counter. So:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol li:before {
  content: 'Q' counter(item, decimal) '. ';
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `list-style-type` by setting it as none:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol li:before {
    content: 'Q' counter(item, decimal) '. ';
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

Look at this demo: http://jsbin.com/paweyadobe/1/

Comment: This work.  Thank you.  I was not seeing it correctly in DW CC in Design more.  I do see it in Live.  Thanks again.